# Non-constexpr conversion of a character into a type

Tags: c++, templates, traits

I'm wondering whether what I'm trying to achieve is possible in `C++`

Suppose I have a template

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo { 
    static void foo();
};
```

and a non-constexpr `char c`.
Now, I want to create an instance of `Foo` and do something with it, depending on the value of my character:

```
if (c == 'i')
    Foo<int>::foo();
else if (c == 'f')
    Foo<float>::foo();
....
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this? I was thinking of maybe writing a `char trait`, like this:

```
template<char c>
struct char_trait {};

template<>
struct char_trait<'i'> {
    using type = int;
};
```

But since `c` is non-constexpr this won't make much sense.

I would appreciate some hints

Comment: if `c` is runtime variable, you cannot use it in template

Comment: Define elegant. What is inelegant about your first solution? How is the second, even if it worked, an improvement?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809541/non-constexpr-conversion-of-a-character-into-a-type#comment68839793_40809541) the template (traits) version wont work for runtime evaluation.

What you could do to avoid a long `if() {} else if()` cascade is to organize your stuff in a map:

```
std::map<char,std::function<void ()>> foo_calls {
    { 'i', Foo<int>::foo } ,
    { 'f', Foo<float>::foo } ,
    // ...
};
```

and use

```
auto it = foo_calls.find(c);
if(it != foo_calls.end) {
    (it->second)();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. All template instantiations in C++ are done at compile time. Good or bad this is so. There is no way to instantiate template at run time.

Although there are tons of different ways of converting the value of a variable into a proper function call. For example you may try:

```
switch (c)
{
    case 'i':
       Foo<int>::foo(); break;
    case 'f':
       Foo<float>::foo(); break;
}
```

This gives more room for compiler to optimize this selection
....